# useEffect returns unhandled promise

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, es6-promise

I have been for several hours trying to get an API to be called in ReactNative `useEffect` hook. Sometimes when I restart my app the value is resolved. But most of the time, I have an `Unhandled promise rejection`.   I googled and tried various methods. I tried using `.then` etc.. I just can't figure it out.

```js
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { EvilIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import jsonServer from '../api/jsonServer';
    
const ShowScreen = ({ navigation }) => {  
  const id = navigation.getParam('id'); 
  const [post, setPost] = useState([]);  

  const getBlog = async () => {
  const result = await jsonServer.get(`http://0.0.0.0/blog/docroot/jsonapi/node/article/${id}`);
    return result;
  }  

  useEffect(() => {        
    async function setToState() {
      const val =  await getBlog();
      setPost(val);   
    }
    setToState();    
  },[]);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Here {  console.log(post) }</Text>        
    </View>
  );
};

ShowScreen.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  return {
    headerRight: (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.navigate('Edit', { id: navigation.getParam('id')
        })}
      >
        <EvilIcons name="pencil" size={35} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  };
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default ShowScreen;
```

Comment: jsonServer is returning a promise. Are you handling that?

Comment: try simplifying your code to debug it, move the call jsonServer.get to setToState and wrap the body in try catch and add the id in the dependency array of useEffect to avoid extra calls in re-renders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think my issue was not just `promise`, the issue is also seems to be me not handling undefined/null in the state. The below code is working for me.

```js
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { EvilIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import jsonServer from '../api/jsonServer';

const ShowScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const id = navigation.getParam('id'); 
  const [post, setPost] = useState([]);      

  const getBlog = async () => {
    const result = await jsonServer.get(`http://hello.com/jsonapi/node/article/${id}`).then(
        res => {         
            setPost(res)
            return res;
        }, err => { 
            console.log(err); 
  });        
  }  

  useEffect(() => {  
    setPost(getBlog());             
  },[]);

  return (
    <View>
        <Text>{ post.data ? post.data.data.id : "" }</Text>                        
    </View>
  );
};            

export default ShowScreen;
```

**Note:** I am setting the state in `useEffect` as well as in the request. I am yet to check if I can just do it once.

Comment: An `async` function always returns a Promise. The `return result;` line will resolve the Promise with the value `result`. The Promise still needs to be awaited or `.then`'d.

Comment: @RossAllen Thanks for the hint. I was able to update my code to use then.

Comment: What about the catch block?? What if the promise is rejected?

Comment: @pratap My final version of code had error handling. However, this solves the issue I pointed out in the original question. I will try to post an updated code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is something like this:

```
....
....

const [post, setPost] = useState([]); 
const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false);  

const getBlog = async () => {
    const result = await jsonServer.get(`http://0.0.0.0/blog/docroot/jsonapi/node/article/${id}`);
    return result;
  }  

useEffect(() => {
     setIsMounted(true)
    async function setToState() {
     // using try catch I'm handling any type of rejection from promises. All errors will move to catch block.
      try{
         const val =  await getBlog();
          // checking if component is still mounted. If mounted then setting a value. We shouldn't update state on an unmounted component.
           if(isMounted){
              setPost(val);
           }
         } catch(err){
        console.log("Error", err)
     }
    }    

    setToState();
    return () => {
     // Setting is mounted to false as the component is unmounted.
     setIsMounted(false)
   }
  },[]);
```

I believe this will solve your Unhandled promise rejection error. Please try if it still doesn't solve the issue will create the same in Sanck.